# DataGridViewComboBoxCell back color changes

Tags: winforms, datagridview

DataGridViewComboBoxCell displays normal when application launched

[image]

After selecting the value, background changes to black (see below) on the current row and subsequent rows. I have used default DataGridView and no font manipulation

[image]

I have tried changing color in CellFormatting and CellMouseClick events. But still the same behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is documented bug with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. [Link with solution and workaround](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/c-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-drop-down-menu-appears-all-black/)

Comment: Great job on finding this and posting a link to the workaround as well. Unlike other resources on the net, the solution posted in the link works. You should copy the solution from the blog over to this answer itself, just in case the blog entry gets eaten by the bit bucket somehow.

Answer (score 0):

https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/c-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-drop-down-menu-appears-all-black/

C#: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Drop Down Menu Appears All Black
December 20, 2010 — Nick Olsen

I ran into an issue today using the DataGridView where one of the columns defined as a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn appeared with the drop down menu completely black as shown below.

After some research I found out that there is a documented bug in the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn where this sometimes occurs if you are handling the EditingControlShowing event of the DataGridView. I am handling this event in order to wire up the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ComboBox embedded in the DataGridView cell.

On the bug report, Microsoft states that they will not be fixing this bug but thankfully, Debanjan1 has posted a workaround for this issue. If you simply set the CellStyle.BackColor property to the DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor in the EditingControlShowing event, the problem goes away. This is shown below.

private void dataGridViewGLEntries_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
ComboBox cmbBx = e.Control as ComboBox;

```
if (cmbBx != null)
{
    cmbBx.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged;
    cmbBx.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged;

    // Fix the black background on the drop down menu
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = this.dataGridViewGLEntries.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
}
```

}